# DFS Traversal: Nodes are printing in reverse order

Tags: c++, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I was doing DFS traversal of graphs.
This is my code:

```
//Function to return a list containing the DFS traversal of the graph.
    vector<int>dfsOfGraph(int V, vector<int> adj[])
    {
        vector<int> res;//value to return
        bool to_visit[V];
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++){//making all nodes to be visited
            to_visit[i]=true;
        }
        stack<int> stack1,stack2;//stack 2 is additional stack to reverse order of nodes
        stack1.push(0);
        to_visit[0]=false;
        while(!(stack1.empty())){
            int x=stack1.top();
            res.push_back(x);
            stack1.pop();
            for(auto iter:adj[x]){
                if(to_visit[iter]){
                    stack2.push(iter);
                    to_visit[iter]=false;
                }
                while(!stack2.empty()){
                    x=stack2.top();
                    stack1.push(x);
                    stack2.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

This code prints nodes in reverse of order of numbers even after I have used an additional stack to reverse the order.
I am not able to figure out why it still printing nodes in reverse order.
Here is full code [link](https://ideone.com/0VH64o)

Answer (score 0):

Using a second stack to reverse the order of nodes visited is an inefficient use of both memory and time, even if it was correctly implemented.

Remove the second stack.

When you have the nodes visited in a vector ( res ) , you can simply reverse the order using the [STL algorithm function reverse](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) just before you return from your function.

```
std::reverse( res.begin(), res.end() );
```